# Add 3 tables using this recource in app script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets-api

I was reading this blog and I wanted to implement the same what he did in there but with two more tables, I was able to get the data but pushing each one to the correct table was not possible, as it pushes the last returned values to the first table.
here is the blog https://www.bpwebs.com/pull-data-from-google-sheets-to-html-table/
and here is my code as it is mentioned in the blog above

this is the HTML file

```
<html>
       <head>
          <base target="_top">
          <!--INCLUDE REQUIRED EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT AND CSS LIBRARIES-->
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>      
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?><!--INCLUDE JavaScript.html FILE-->
          <?!= include('StyleCSS'); ?>
          <?!= include('StyleCSSmini'); ?>
          <?!= include('Bootstrap1'); ?>
          <?!= include('Bootstrap2'); ?>
          <?!= include('dataTablesmin'); ?>
       </head>
       <title></title>
       <body class="maincontainer">
          <div class="header">
             <h5>Admins View</h5>
          </div>
          <section class="container1">
             <br><br><br><br>
             <div id="col-1">
                <div id="table-wrapper">
                   <div id="table-scroll">
                      <br><br>
                      <table id="data-table-1" style= "align:center;text-align:center;" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
                         <!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ABOVE -->
                      </table>
                   </div>
                   <br><br>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div id="col-2">
                <br><br>
                <div class="row">
                   <div id="table-wrapper">
                      <div id="table-scroll">
                         <br><br>
                         <table id="data-table-2" style= "align:center;text-align:center;" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
                            <!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ABOVE -->
                         </table>
                      </div>
                      <br><br>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div id="col-3">
                <div id="table-wrapper">
                   <div id="table-scroll">
                      <br><br>
                      <table id="data-table-3" style= "align:center;text-align:center;" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
                         <!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ABOVE -->
                      </table>
                   </div>
                   <br><br>
                </div>
             </div>
          </section>
          <div>
             <div class="footer">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                   <br><br>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

---

### this is in indexgs

```
        function doGet() {
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
    }
    
    //GET DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET AND RETURN AS AN ARRAY
    function getData() {
    
      var spreadSheetId = "1_eBCSgD2Uzyh9pvB0v2Qu3Sl_T4NaW7HkpQ9iAtN3Ig"; //CHANGE
    
      var dataRange1 = "Sheet1!A2:E"; //CHANGE
    
      var range1 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange1);
      var values1 = range1.values;
    
    
    
      return values1; 
      
    }
    
    function getData() {
    
      var spreadSheetId = "1_eBCSgD2Uzyh9pvB0v2Qu3Sl_T4NaW7HkpQ9iAtN3Ig"; //CHANGE
    
    
    
    
      var dataRange2 = "sheet2!A2:D"; //CHANGE
    
      var range2 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange2);
    
      var values2 = range2.values;
    
    
      return values2;                             ;
      
    }
    
    
    function getData() {
    
      var spreadSheetId = "1_eBCSgD2Uzyh9pvB0v2Qu3Sl_T4NaW7HkpQ9iAtN3Ig"; //CHANGE
    
    
    
    
      var dataRange3 = "sheet3!A2:D"; //CHANGE
    
      var range3 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange3);
    
      var values3 = range3.values;
    
    
      return values3; 
      
    }
    

    //INCLUDE JAVASCRIPT AND CSS FILES
    //REF: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript
    
    function include(filename) {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
        .getContent();
    }
    
    //Ref: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/145428/#Comment_145428
    //Ref: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4
```

---

### this is in javascript.html

```
//THIS FUNCTION GENERATE THE DATA TABLE FROM THE DATA ARRAY
  function showData(dataArray){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table-1').DataTable({
        data: dataArray,
        lengthMenu: [
          [3000, 6000, 9000, 12000],
          [3000, 6000, 9000, 12000],
        ],
        //CHANGE THE TABLE HEADINGS BELOW TO MATCH WITH YOUR SELECTED DATA RANGE
        columns: [
          {"title":"Model"},
          {"title":"Serial Number"},
          {"title":"Layout"},
          {"title":"AD"},
          {"title":"Email"},
        ]
      });
    });
  }

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData1).getData();

  //THIS FUNCTION GENERATE THE DATA TABLE FROM THE DATA ARRAY

    function showData1(dataArray1){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table-2').DataTable({
        data1: dataArray1,
        lengthMenu: [
          [3000, 6000, 9000, 12000],
          [3000, 6000, 9000, 12000],
        ],
        //CHANGE THE TABLE HEADINGS BELOW TO MATCH WITH YOUR SELECTED DATA RANGE
        columns: [
          {"title":"Serial Number"},
          {"title":"User Name/Email"},
          {"title":"Info"},
          {"title":"Device Type"},
        ]
      });
    });
  }

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData2).getData();

  //THIS FUNCTION GENERATE THE DATA TABLE FROM THE DATA ARRAY

    function showData2(dataArray2){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table-3').DataTable({
        data2: dataArray2,
        lengthMenu: [
          [3000, 6000, 9000, 12000],
          [3000, 6000, 9000, 12000],
        ],
        //CHANGE THE TABLE HEADINGS BELOW TO MATCH WITH YOUR SELECTED DATA RANGE
        columns: [
          {"title":"IMEI"},
          {"title":"User Name"},
          {"title":"Email"},
          {"title":"Model"},
        ]
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: You should include your html.  I'm assuming you are using google.script.run.getData().  But you have three functions named getData() only one of them, probabaly the first will execute.

Comment: hi @TheWizEd I just updated the code and I included the Html and the javascript there

Comment: It's not clear what code is in html files and what in gs files.

Comment: I just separated them can you check that, thank you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The question format still should be improved and it looks that a couple of comments were misplaced but considering the answer that it's already posted I think that it's fair to say that the current question state is good enough. For your next question please pay more attention to the question format (don't include so much white space, put the code in a logical order, in this case the  .gs code should be first, then the html file for the document structure, then the html file for the client-side javascript.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting close, but you need to get acquainted with the documentation to better understand how the [success handlers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction) work. For example, this line:

```js
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();
```

This is saying "run the server-side function `getData()`, then if it succeeds, run the client-side function `showData()` and pass it the values returned from the server".

In your case you declared `getData()` in the server-side three times, which just overwrites it so you're just running the same function three times and getting the same result. You should have named the server functions `getData()`, `getData1()` and `getData2()` to correspond to the local `showData()`,  `showData1()` and `showData2()`, then call them like this:

```js
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData1).getData1();
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData2).getData2();
```

But I think there are better ways to do it. If you rewrite the functions you can avoid repeating the `getData()` and `showData()` functions. You can replace them with this:

##### Javascript.html:

```js
  function showData(dataArray, table){
      var headers = dataArray.shift()
      var columns = []
      for (var header in headers){
        columns.push({"title": headers[header]})
      }
      table.DataTable({
        data: dataArray,
        lengthMenu: [
          [3000, 6000, 9000, 12000],
          [3000, 6000, 9000, 12000],
        ],
        columns: columns
      });
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).withUserObject($('#data-table-1')).getData("Sheet1!A1:E");
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).withUserObject($('#data-table-2')).getData("Sheet2!A1:D");
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).withUserObject($('#data-table-3')).getData("Sheet3!A1:D");
});
```

##### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}

function getData(dataRange) {

  var spreadSheetId = "your-id"; 
  var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange);
  var values = range.values;
  return values;

}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
    .getContent();
}
```

##### Explanation:

- I added a `range` parameter to `getData()` so you can just send the A1 notation of the sheet to the server without having to write one function for each range.
- I included the top row in the range so you can use [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to pull the header names directly from the sheet.
- I also added [`withUserObject()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withuserobjectobject) to send a reference to the table element back to the callback function.

In the end to build your tables you just need to add this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).withUserObject($('#data-table-1')).getData("Sheet1!A1:E");
});
```

Where you only have to specify the table object `$('#data-table-1')` and the sheet range `"Sheet1!A1:E"`. There's still room for improvement so I recommend you check out the documentation to get a feel for how it works.

##### Sources:

- [Communicating with server functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really liked the way you optimized the code, and thanks for the clarification, it is now running as expected